# Difference between launching app from recents and home screen

Tags: android, kotlin, android-manifest

I have ActivityA as launcher activity.

From ActivityA I open -> ActivityB. I put the app in background.

When I open the app from recents the app is resumed with ActivityB.
When I open the app from homescreen, the app is resumed with ActivityA without calling onCreate(), just onResume().

Why is ActivityB cleared from stack when I open the app from homescreen, even if onCreate() from ActivityA is never called, and how to fix this?

Manifest file looks like this:

ActivityA:

```
 <activity-alias
            android:name=".Launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:targetActivity="path.ActivityA">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity-alias>

        <activity
            android:name=".path.ActivityA"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"
            android:theme="@style/BlackIntroTheme"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
            <nav-graph android:value="@navigation/graph1" />
            <nav-graph android:value="@navigation/graph2" />
            <nav-graph android:value="@navigation/graph3" />
            <nav-graph android:value="@navigation/graph4" />
        </activity>
```

ActivityB:

```
  <activity
            android:name=".path.ActivityB"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this is how `Activity` stacking works, some nice example of all `launchMode`s in [HERE](https://medium.com/@iammert/android-launchmode-visualized-8843fc833dbe), more complex info in [DOCs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#lmode)

in short - `Activity` with `singleTask` started (again) will clear all on-top-of-it `Activities`. you have your first `MAIN` `Activity` declared with this `launchMode`, so every icon click on devices launcher will clear your `Activities` stack. you can track this by overriding `onNewIntent` method. picking from recents just brings all your `Activities` stack to front, with last opened on top ofc.

consider removing `launchMode` (is this necessary line for you?) or set it as `standard` (default)

```
android:launchMode="standard"
```